# Converting a Query to Django ORM Code

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, orm

I want to perform this query to get the id of all the groups that are associated with the table auth_group_permissions.

```
select id from auth_group where id in (select group_id from auth_group_permissions group by group_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models `Group` and `Permission` are connected to each other via [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field `permissions`. See the [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L116)

Based on the info I found in internet and based on what I remember, you need to do the next:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

grouped_permissions = Permission.objects.order_by().distinct('group_id')
your_ids = Group.objects.filter(permissions__group_id__in=grouped_permissions).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I read the documentation well and got the answer. But he served me.

Answer (score 0):

That's the final correct answer.

```
grouped_permissions = Permission.objects.filter().order_by().distinct().values_list('group__id',flat=True) 
your_ids = Group.objects.filter(id__in = grouped_permissions)
```